# Is there a way to restore an uninstalled executable from bin?

Tags: linux, filesystems, python, executable, pip

I tried upgrading pip3 using `su -c 'pip3 install' --upgrade pip'` because I got errors and it failed when trying to upgrade it as a normal user.

This removed the pre-installed pip from `/usr/bin` and dumped it in `/tmp`, replacing it with a system wide installation of pip which is only accessible by root. I haven't tried to uninstall this new pip because I suspect it would lead to more problems.

Since I still have the old pre-installed pip in `/tmp`, how do I get back the pre-installed pip using this executable that is still in /tmp?

#### Location of pip in /tmp:

```
/tmp/pip-ufkfr3th-uninstall
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── pip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that this was the package manager's version of `pip`, I'd simply re-install using your package manager.

*Fedora/CentOS*

```
$ sudo yum reinstall python-pip
```

*Debian/Ubuntu*

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y python-pip
```

Comment: At least in Debian python installed pip and the pip from the distro *usually* live in different places.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - right, the OP said `/usr/bin` so that would fall in the realm of package managers.

Comment: @slm yes it was the RPM version that pip removed which is why there are a few broken symlinks in `/usr/bin`, pip installed its own version in `usr/local/bin`. This makes me want to consider using git to track `/usr/bin`. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - yeah there's no need, the `/usr/bin` directory is owned by the package managers, so you really shouldn't be doing anything around them. Let the distros' tools for package management do their jobs.

Comment: Right, no need for git then. I've solved it by the way. There was no need to re-install from the fedora repo.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - awesome.

Comment: Thanks @slm. What do you think would have happened if I copied `/tmp/pip-ufkfr3th-uninstall/usr/bin/pip` to `/usr/bin`? I'm curious if that could have also worked.

Comment: yeah, normally you have to manually delete the python installed one under /usr/local/...

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - that probably would've worked. You  have to be careful w/ this directory b/c the package managers maintain a sudo database of what the state of things are in there, you can introduce discrepancies if you start mucking around w/ it.

Comment: @slm I see. If the database says `pip` was removed and I manually re-introduced it then there may be no record of it being there and a `dnf update` may not work. Thanks for the warning, I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - Yes things like that. Permissions, ownership, etc can also become an issue.

Comment: Also, make sure the SELinux labels are correct. (`sudo restorecon /usr/bin/pip`)

Comment: @mattdm I didn't receive an alert for your comment. Is the command you posted necessary and can you expand on the significance of what you mentioned?

Comment: That's probably a whole question on its own. SELinux is a _mandatory access control_ system in the Linux kernel, and it uses filesystem labels (which you can see with `ls -Z`) to determine some of what is permitted. If you just copy a file around without properly preserving the labels, you will get a mismatch with the security policy and may not be able to run things. `restorecon` puts them back to how they're expected.

Comment: @slm In order to avoid conflicts with dnf, if I want to install a package that was already installed by dnf using pip, whats the right way to do it? Is it to allow pip to uninstall the system package and replaced it, or to run `dnf remove` first before using pip? I'm finding the problem with the former is that `dnf info` still thinks the package is installed while for the latter `dnf remove` tries to uninstall dozens of dependencies.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia you should be using dnf exclusively for pkg mgmt. If you find yourself wanting to use pip I'd switch my approach and use virtualenv to mange python + pip installed pkgs per coding project. The system python is really meant for the systems software not yours.

Comment: https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/